# Why aren't nodes adding properly and why is it printing in reverse? (singly linked list)

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

**SOLVED**

The problem could also be solved by copying the head into another variable after adding new nodes. 
A more logical solution would be to do as the answer says.

---

---

I'm practicing on a simple linked list implementation, wanted to explore pointers more too. why doesn't my code add nodes properly?

```
typedef struct Node{

    int info;

    struct Node* next;

}Node;

void createList(Node** node, int info){

        *node = calloc(1, sizeof(Node));
        (*node)->info = info;
        (*node)->next = NULL;

}
Node* newNode(int info)
{
    Node* newNode;
    newNode = calloc(1, sizeof(Node));
    newNode->info = info;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    return newNode;
}

void addNode(Node** node, int info){
    int adaugat = 0;


    if(*node == NULL){

        createList(node, info);
        adaugat = 1; 
    }

    if(adaugat == 0)
    {
        Node **aux = node;
        while((*aux)->next != NULL)
        {
            *aux = (*aux)->next;
        }
        (*aux)->next = newNode(info);
        adaugat = 1;
    }

}
void printList(Node* node){
    int i = 1;
    Node* aux;
    aux = node;
    while(aux != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d_[%d]--",i, aux->info );
        i++;
        aux = aux->next;
    }
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Node *nod = NULL;
    int key = 5;

    createList(&nod, key);

    addNode(&nod, 5);
    addNode(&nod, 3);
    addNode(&nod, 4);
    addNode(&nod, 1);

    printList(nod);

    return 0;
}
```

I've attempted shifting around with pointers and function calling inputs in main() but all I got were more warnings and segfaults. 
The output here from main() is `1_[4]--2_[1]--` when it should have been

```
1_[5]--2_[3]--3_[4]--4_[1]--
```

Comment: Why do you need an extra node for the head of the list? `Node *nod` already is the head, so `createList()` is redundant. A simple linked list is like a LIFO stack: that's why the print is in reverse order.

Comment: `createList()` serves as Init at the same time, are you suggesting this approach is causing me the issues?  I started from head with the printing though, i don't understand why it's reverse...

Comment: Oh, I see, you are trying to add each item to the tail of the list. In a simple list, you add each new item at the front. The whole thing seems over complicated.

Comment: Adding to tail of list doesn't work? IIRC all simply linked lists in labs at my college added from head to tail. This work is a little test for me because I've been working with ready-made-fill-in-blanks .h files, complete with a big test .c file. Needed something fresh.

Comment: To me, it's defeating the point of a linked list if you have to parse the entire list to add a new item. If you want them the other way round, insert them the other way round.

Comment: The head pointer `nod` at the beginning and at the end does not point to the same place.

Comment: @永劫回帰  i dont follow, would you kindly point out in more detail where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this snippet of the function `addNode`

```c
if(adaugat == 0)
    {
        Node **aux = node;
        while((*aux)->next != NULL)
        {
            *aux = (*aux)->next;
        }
        (*aux)->next = newNode(info);
        adaugat = 1;
    }
```

more precisely on the line `*aux = (*aux)->next;` you are shifting the list at the same time you are walking through it because of the `Node ** aux`. Hence it will always look like your list has two elements.

If you want to add an element at the end of the list, you have to traverse the list without modifying it, that is,

```c
if(adaugat == 0)
    {
        Node *aux = *node;
        while(aux->next != NULL)
        {
            aux = aux->next;
        }
        aux->next = newNode(info);
        adaugat = 1;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to fix it. I just copied head when creating the list before adding any nodes.

Comment: Sorry for revoking accept, I was too quick to accept and got an issue. but it turns out it was just my fault. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the following block of code

```
    if(adaugat == 0)
    {
        Node **aux = node;
        while((*aux)->next != NULL)
        {
            *aux = (*aux)->next;
        }
        (*aux)->next = newNode(info);
        adaugat = 1;
    }
```

The variable `node` is not getting dereferenced and using a double pointer here is unnecessary. Changing that part to the following will give you the desired output...

```
    if(adaugat == 0)
    {
        Node *aux = *node;
        while(aux->next != NULL)
        {
            aux = aux->next;
        }
        aux->next = newNode(info);
        adaugat = 1;
    }
```

Hope this helps.